# tune rrd to increase step and heartbeat (x2)

Tags: nagios, rrdtool, rrd, cacti

I've got a bunch of rrds being updated every 5min

```
step = 300
ds[ExeTime].minimal_heartbeat = 600
```

I need to change this to every 15min.

rrdtool tune allows me to change the heartbeat but not the steps.  Can I simply change the heartbeat to 1800? (900 = 15min .. then x2 for heartbeat) ??

Will this leave a bunch of holes making avg/max/etc off?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server monitoring, not programming, so probably better suited to serverfault.

Comment: understood ( did post there too ).  I figured since there were a bunch of other rrd questions in here along with the tags it would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the step of your rrd file it has to be rewritten ... check out https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-rrdjig

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: the essential part of the answer is, that the rrd file has to be re-written from scratch, essentially re-sampling the data at a lower rate ... the link points to a program that does this.

Comment: Does your tool create a new rrd? Does it replace the existing rrd? What usage parameters would answer the original question?